# How to add external controls?

Tags: jquery, slider, rotator

Like links "next/back" and a loop, for this script - http://thejavascriptblog.com/the-quotator-the-json-driven-html-rotator/

Or searcing some other jQuery script for rotating text with fade effect and external controls.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for http://www.php-help.ro/examples/mootools_rotator/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Mike Alsup's cycle plug-in for jQuery would be just the thing; it does text as well as images. Check out http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/int2.html for an example with a next/prev option.